# Export to CSV, with wrap characters and skip headers

Tags: excel

Is there a way to export Excel to a csv file that wraps EVERY cell in " and skips the headers? Save-as .csv is not the answer I am looking for.

I am looking for a way to do this from within excel if it is possible. Not a coding solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in Sheet1, the best non-VBA solution I can think of is to add a second sheet and enter a formula in A1 like the following:

```
=""""&Sheet1!A1&""","""&Sheet1!B1&""","""&Sheet1!C1&""""
```

Then copy that down for as many rows as you have in Sheet1.  You need to extend this formula for as many columns as you have as well.

This will give you a single column looking like the CSV file format you want.  You would then save that page as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in the activesheet at cell A1 with a first header row, the attached code should write it to a csv file to your specs.

```
Sub WriteToCSV()

Const forReading = 1, forAppending = 3, fsoForWriting = 2
Dim fs, objTextStream, sText As String
Dim lLastRow As Long, lRowLoop As Long, lLastCol As Long, lColLoop As Long

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextStream = fs.opentextfile("c:\temp\myResult.csv", fsoForWriting, True)

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For lRowLoop = 2 To lLastRow
    sText = ""
    For lColLoop = 1 To lLastCol
        sText = sText & Chr(34) & Cells(lRowLoop, lColLoop) & Chr(34) & ","
    Next lColLoop

    objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText, Len(sText) - 1))
Next

objTextStream.Close
Set objTextStream = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: another option to loop through all used cells is 

    `For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells`

then use `cell.row` to check if you need to add a EOL character

Comment: I am looking for a non-coding answer. Something you can do from within Excel if that is possible. I will edit my question for clarity.